# JavaFX WebEngine Video Playback in Linux

Tags: java, video, javafx, redhat, codec

We are currently having issues developing within the WebViewer in JavaFX on our Linux Redhat 6 environment. Using JavaFX 2.2 and Java 1.7.0.51 we have a WebViewer that goes to an HTML page with a video tag in it.

It works perfectly on our Windows boxes but, on the linux box we get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:704)
    at com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCMediaPlayerImpl.prepareToPlay(WCMediaPlayerImpl.java:208)
    at com.sun.webpane.platform.graphics.WCMediaPlayer.fwkPrepareToPlay(WCMediaPlayer.java:290)
    at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.twkProcessMouseEvent(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.dispatchMouseEvent(WebPage.java:751)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebView.processMouseEvent(WebView.java:983)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebView.access$2600(WebView.java:81)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebView$14.handle(WebView.java:1136)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebView$14.handle(WebView.java:1134)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3369)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3209)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3164)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1582)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2267)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.EmbeddedScene$2$1.run(EmbeddedScene.java:194)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.EmbeddedScene$2$1.run(EmbeddedScene.java:176)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.EmbeddedScene$2.run(EmbeddedScene.java:176)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I will state the obvious, it seems the thread that is being spawned off of the JavaFX is dying when it is trying to load the video.  Has anyone else experienced issues of this nature? Any ideas on what to try?  We have tried using very specific codec versions of H-264, but that has not worked. Any idea on how you all set up your linux/javafx environment for video playback in the JavaFX WebView would be helpful as well.

Also, to clarify the application is Swing with embedded JavaFX, however it still occurs in a pure JavaFX implementation as well, slightly different Exception.

Thanks, 
Nathan

Update:  Looks like we may not have the codecs installed correctly.  Will update with an answer tomorrow for future reference.

Comment: Red Hat 6 is not a supported configuration for JavaFX 2, but is a [supported configuration for JavaFX in Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html).  Try Java 8 and see if it works.  If not, file a [bug report](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) against the JavaFX runtime project.

Comment: Right now it is looking like we didn't install the codec correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that we did not have any/correct codecs built into the OS properly and that it had to be a very specific version of the codec.  While, Redhat 6.5 is not supported by the configuration, it still works as advertised on the distribution.  The codecs that we are using are: libavcodec52 and libavformat52, as mentioned here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html

It is a shame that the exception gave no explanation of what was truly going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! In case any Arch Linux user is looking for the solution, check out this: https://bbs.archlinux.de/viewtopic.php?pid=311353#p311353